# Pandas - group by ID, assign category

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with approx 60,000 records that looks like this:

```
             ID     P1   YEAR
     0  20184045    MK   2020   
     1  20184045    GF   2020   
     2  20184011    EC   2020   
     3  20184011    MK   2020   
     4  20184011    EC   2020   
     5  20180673    GF   2020
```

Where ID is the ID of the record (8-digit integer), which has a P1 property that can take 10 distinct values (all are 2-char strings) and year is between 1995 and 2020. Each ID can have records that have between 1 and 5 different year values.
I want to obtain 2 additional dataframes:
one that gives me information about the number of distinct values of P1 for each year and each ID  that would look like this:

```
    ID          YEAR       NUMBER OF DISTINCT VALUES OF P1 FOR EACH YEAR
0   20184045    2020                         n
1   20184045    2019
2   20184045    2018
3   20184045    2017
4   20184011    2020
5   20180673    2020
```

My second dataframe would count the total number of distinct values of P1 for each ID.

```
    ID            NUMBER OF DISTINCT VALUES OF P1 OVERALL
0   123                        n1
1   456                        n2
2   789                        n3
3   987                        n4
4   654                        n1
5   321                        n2
```

I tried looking up how to iterate over a dataframe with iterrows() and iteritems() but I have been unable to find how to iterate over 3 columns at the same time and grouping by id.

I've also looked into itertuples() which yields namedtuples and seemed more promising but I've been unable to find a satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make do with two groupby:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['ID','YEAR'])['P1']
         .nunique()
         .reset_index(name='Number of Unique P1')
      )

df2 = (df.groupby('YEAR')['P1']
         .nunique()
         .reset_index(name='Number of Unique P1')
      )
```

Comment: darn, you beat me to it!